# Multithreading advice

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I am developing an application, the main goal is to grab images from a frame grabber, do some processing and then show images on a GUI.
The frame grabber is connected to the PCIe. And I'm using the frame grabber SDK.
The image stream is pretty slow 10 to 100 images/s 
I am here to have some advice about my code and how to optimize it. 
First, there is my run() function from a class inherited from Qthread
I grab an image and put it on a buffer queuecv:: Mat>.

```
void ImageIn::run(){
        _cam->allocMemory();
        _cam->startAquisition();
        _runningThread = true;

        while(_runningThread)
        {
             Mat image(_cam.getSizeX(), _cam.getSizeY(), CV_16U, _cam->getImageDMA0());

             _ctrl->getMutexIn()->lock(); // Lock BufferIn
             _ctrl->getBufferIn()->push(image); // store Image in BufferIn
             _ctrl->getMutexIn()->unlock(); // Unlock bufferIn
        }

}
```

Images are stored in a buffer and then the processing thread do some work...

```
void ImageProcessing::run(){
while(_runningThread){
if (_ctrl->getMutexIn()->tryLock()){
    while(!_ctrl->getBufferIn()->empty()){
        _ctrl->getBufferIn()->front().convertTo(tempConvert, CV_32F);
        _bufferLocalIn.push(tempConvert);
        _ctrl->getBufferIn()->pop();
    }
    _ctrl->getMutexIn()->unlock();
}

// Do some processing and put image and a buffer for GUI
}
}
```

So, I have some questions: 
- The thread 1 gets images thanks to a blocking function, so the CPU consumption is low, but the thread 2 run continuously and consumes a lot of CPU reassess what can I do for fixing that? 
- is it the right way to code that?

---

So i tried that :

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
ImageWriter* worker = new ImageWriter();
worker->moveToThread(thread);

QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
int msec = 100;
timer->setInterval(msec);

QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), thread, SLOT(start()));
timer->start();
```

is it ok ?

Comment: read about conditional wait. You can let the 2nd thread wait until the first thread has captured a new image to process. Then it'll continue to process until the list of input images is empty and fall back into the conditional wait. I've got one question: The blocking function is from your frame grabber SDK to wait until a new image is available before trying to grab?

Comment: Thanks i'll read about conditional wait and try that. 
yeah the _cam->getImageDMA0() function call a blocking function from the frame grabber SDK. This blocking function wait for a new image.

Answer (score 2):

As Qt is an event driven framework, each thread has an event queue which receives events and sends them to various objects to receive them.

If any section of code in a thread has essentially a while(1) loop, then event propagation cannot occur and this is what you're doing in both threads with

```
while(_runningThread)
```

Starving the event processing in an infinite loop is the cause of excessive CPU consumption.

It is possible to use to get Qt to process events with a call to [QApplication::processEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) within the infinite loops, but this is not ideal.

A better method would be to time-slice the processing with [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) and allow the event propagation to occur naturally. This would require deciding how long processing could occur, before saving the processing state and then returning back to the event loop. A tick of the timer would call your processing function which can then restore state and resume.

This method will be easier if you create a processing class derived from QObject which you move to a QThread, rather than inheriting directly from QThread itself. There's a great article on [How to Really Truly Use QThread](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) which can be used as a template on how to do this.

Finally, consider that you can have more than one `QThread`, as well as more than one `QObject` running on a `QThread`. As a general rule, you will not benefit if the number of threads exceeds the number of processor cores available.

If you know the target machine is a quad core, you can create 3 extra QThreads (4 in total, including main), create multiple processing objects and move them to different threads to provide optimal processing.

Comment: I'll try this solution too. Is QwaitCondition better than using moveToThread ?

Comment: That's comparing two completely different things. As the docs state for [QWaitCondition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html#details) *The QWaitCondition class provides a condition variable for synchronizing threads*, whereas moveToThread, moves an object to a thread in order for its processing to occur on that thread.

Comment: Ok i'll see. 
So, I've got one question, if the image rate is too fast for processing i'll call too much processing function (moved to a thread) is this unsafe ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. You setup the object which will process all images, then move it to a new thread....you only call moveToThread once. If you receive images quicker than you can process them, you'll have to queue up the images, until they can be processed.

Comment: I strongly suggest reading [the article on QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) first.

Comment: I'll already read it. 
I found it 1 month ago (really good article)